# Locale configuration files 2.4.6 - Currency Format problems

Tags: currency, magento2.4.6, format, currency-symbol

Does anyone know where the configuration files are for currency format and symbol as on 2.4.6?

In this case the 'locale' doesn't exist for the specific country in the options so am using the default Spanish 'es' (es_ES), however the currency format is off showing the currency symbol AFTER the price, and commas and dots being exchanged.

So instead of '$12,000.00' appears '12.000,00 $'

I've used an override to move the symbol but the dots and commas are still wrong.

This used to be defined in the Zend framework I think however now it's in laminas I cannot find where the magento/framework/Locale/Currency options are pulling their data from nor how to override the format to switch the commas and dots.

Surely this has to be defined by each currency somewhere.

Anyone managed to do this without paying $200 for a module?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this free extension for this**: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-currency-formatter